# Attach Security Group to LoadBalancer created by In-Tree EKS Controler

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I've read that recently aws added the possibility to add Security Groups to NLB instead of their targets.

But i struggle when trying to create the NLB through LoadBalancer Annotations.

I've tried to add the following annotation combination to create the nlb with a security group:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-extra-security-groups: sg-asdf1234
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: true
```